# PyGame - mixer.music()

Tags: python, pygame

Eu estou montado um sistema que utiliza às ferramentas do PyGame, em outros termos, estou criando uma aplicação que rode músicas, eu estou a muito tempo, tentando fazer que, com o término da música atual (armazenada em um vetor), a música pulasse para o outro indicie, assim não sendo necessário ficar pressionando Next sempre

Eu já tentei criar um loop `While` utilizando o método `mixer.music.get_busy()`, o qual retorna `True` quando a música está sendo executada e `False` caso contrário, então eu poderia avançar um indicie assim que a música parasse, mas na verdade o Loop fica rodando Finitas vezes até o término da música, causando um bug e travando o sistema, já tentei usar o método `mixer.music.queue()`, o qual passa uma música quando a anterior termina de tocar, porém ainda gera erro.

Estarei deixando abaixo parte do código fonte, para que possam ter uma melhor compreensão do que estou dizendo.

```
def escolherDiretorio (self):
    diretorio = askdirectory()
    os.chdir(diretorio)


    for item in os.listdir():
        #print(item)
        if item.endswith(".mp3"):
            real = os.path.realpath(item)
            musicas.append(item)

    self.musica_atual = mixer.init()
    self.musica_atual = mixer.music.load(musicas[0])
    self.musica_atual = mixer.music.play()

def play (self):
    self.musica_atual = mixer.music.play()

def stop (self):
    self.musica_atual = mixer.music.stop()

def nextM (self):
    global index
    index += 1
    self.musica_atual = mixer.music.load(musicas[index])
    self.musica_atual = mixer.music.play()

def back (self):
    global index
    index -= 1
    self.musica_atual = mixer.music.load(musicas[index])
    self.musica_atual = mixer.music.play()
```

Se puderem me ajudar, ficarei grato.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver esse problema?

Comment: @Blogueira - negativo

Comment: Consegue fazer um [mcve](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Blogueira não entendo muito disso

Comment: A ideia do [mcve](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) é ter um código completo e que possa ser executado para demonstrar o problema. Você consegue reproduzir o seu problema num código novo?